# Make the input of two combo boxes search for, read and display data from csv file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, csv, combobox

Look this question is probably going to be unanswered or really confusing. This is all in Visual Studio (VB Code is preferred).

[image: layout]

I have this program, and basically when the program loads, I want the combo boxes to be populated with data from a CSV file(I have done this.)
Then once I choose a value from the section box, I want the competitor number combo box to only show the numbers that have the selected value from the section box (i.e dependent combo boxes). Then based of the two values chosen, I want a name to be displayed.

So if Section 1, competitor 1 is chosen, I want their name to be displayed. But if I change it to section 1 competitor 2, the name should change.

Comment: Your title makes it obvious what the problem is here. You're treating four separate issues as though they were one. On SO, you MUST ask one specific question at a time. The fact that you're asking so many questions together means that you haven't actually broken it down into parts and considered each part on its own, which is probably why you can't solve the problem on your own to begin with. Break your problem down into the smallest parts you can, address each one separately, solve the parts you can and then ask here about ONE specific issue at a time. Divide and conquer.

Comment: I’ve been able to do the first two steps - I know how to read a CSV and input that into combo boxes… once I’ve done that I’ve got not clue.

Comment: Then why are those steps part of the question? Edit your question and provide information about the SPECIFIC issue you need help with. Provide everything that's relevant and nothing that isn't, to the best of your ability.

Comment: See edits. Hopefully it makes sense

Comment: The info your already reading from the csv files, what have you done with that?  Is it floating around in a dataset somewhere?  Maybe you should expand you question with where exactly your at so we can see your data structures and advise how to do the search

Comment: Exact names of the combo boxes and label? Sample CSV data? Code from an existing attempt? If you've already loaded the csv data, where and how it stored in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Build a class for your competitor object.

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property ComboBox1Value As String
    Public Property ComboBox2Value As String
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

Then declare a collection to hold the list of objects somewhere. I added it to the top of Form1.vb. Now when you hit your Search_For_Name sub, just loop through the collection until the combobox values match those in one of the objects.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim MyCollection As New Collection

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Populate your collection here from your csv by declaring a new
        'person for each row of your file, and then adding it to the 
        'collection.
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        Search_For_Name()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedValueChanged
        Search_For_Name()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Search_For_Name()
        For Each P As Person In MyCollection
            If P.ComboBox1Value = ComboBox1.Text And P.ComboBox2Value = ComboBox2.Text Then
                TextBox1.Text = P.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I have - what I'm struggling with is making the code apply to potentially limitless data...

Comment: ahh, so you are wanting to know how to handle the search? hang on. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This has to almost one of the worse ways to implement the search.  At least break out of the loop if the match is found.  would benefit from the use of AndAlso too which will short circuit the if conditional

Comment: Added an exit for, just for you Hursey.